# How to deploy a container from ACR to AKS using Helm

Tags: azure, ansible, kubernetes-helm

I am using Ansible for the first time
I want to deploy an ACR (Azure container registry) service to AKS (Azure Kubenetes Service) using Helm.

I have setup the AKS.
I have an ACR service.

Please show me how to deploy a container from ACR to AKS using Helm.

Comment: ok, first of all, you cannot setup AKS on centos, it only supports ubuntu. you cannot setup ACR **ON** AKS. AKS can use ACR to pull images, but its not hosting ACR. Also, given that you are asking this, my answer to the previous question clearly helped you, so consider accepting it

Comment: sorry , i'm wrong. i fixed issue . Please

Comment: I fixed "I want to use ACR to pull image , then deploy it to AKS using Helm and Ansible Playbook."

Comment: i fixed , please give me answer :D

Comment: this is actually a dupe, check the linked answer

Comment: Deploy a container from ACR to AKS using Helm .Not [Deploy a container from ACR to AKS] ,  [Deploy a container from ACR to AKS ]will use YAML file . Is it duplicate ?

Comment: it doesnt matter. helm is basically a templating engine for yaml files. you can follow the helm quickstart: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md